# Web Application, which route to go?

Tags: c#, java, silverlight, web-applications

I'm going to develop a web application based on mathematics. It's going to provide stuff like canvas' showing graphs (quadratics etc.) and also provide an exercise area to test knowledge.

I am stuck as to which route to take. I haven't developed a Web Application before and I am most confident working in C# applications. I would prefer to use C# when creating this but I don't know if that is really appropriate.

I have the following routes that I could go down:

- Silverlight - I haven't used this before but it seems to be the most obvious solution to me. I was wondering how hard it will be to develop an understanding of silverlight (xaml etc.)
- Java, I haven't any idea about java, but I've heard it has a lot of similarities to C#.
- Tclets, my university tutor said he has worked with this before and it's easier to get on the web, and very handy for gui's.

I thought I'd ask this here to get everyones opinion on which path to take, and sum up all the positives and negatives of each route.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you decide to go the Silverlight route the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) has some good graphing samples : [Silverlight Toolkit Control Samples](http://silverlight.net/content/samples/sl3/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html) - which is itself a Silverlight application.

Using Silverlight is probably the closest you can get to writing a desktop application for the web. The UI is specified in XAML with the application layer in C#. The whole application sits within the Silverlight control and you can generate the menus and other navigation items you need.

It complies to a XAP file which you deploy and then reference from either an HTML page or ASP page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are most comfortable with C# then I would advise developing it in ASP.NET. Heres a starting point: [Creating ASP.NET Web Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywdtth2f(VS.71).aspx)

Comment: I don't know where it came from, but to my understanding Asp.net was for people who required database like web applications. Is it suitable for 2D graphics?

Comment: I suppose it depends on exactly what it is you intend to do. However, ASP.NET has its own Charting control which you might find very handy. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I really can't speak to Java or Tclets but Silverlight will offer you a familiar programming model if you are most comfortable in C#.  XAML requires a bit of a learning curve if you don't have any experience with it.  You don't have to go 100% Silverlight though - it could be a hybrid HTML (ASP.NET) and Silverlight solution - where Silverlight could primarily be used for the graphing/charting.  You could use HTML or a more sophisticated ASP.NET site for the remainder of the content.